# Assembly - wrong implementation of free list

Tags: assembly, x86

I read a book, which give the next example:
There is a list, which each member has the next member's adress in it four first bytes. The last member has the value of 0. It say that the next implementation is wrong, and I don't understand why:

```
freeList
   mov eax, [ebp+8]
   cmp eax, 0
   jne cont
   ret
cont:
   mov ebx, [eax]
   mov [ebp+8], ebx
   push eax
   call free
   pop eax
   call freeList
```

(I don't need the correct implementation, I have one. I just need to understand what wrong with this one)

Thanks.

Comment: The `call freeList` at the end looks wrong to me, my best guess is that is should say `jmp freeList`.

Comment: @Neil: In the correct answer, it's really jmp. What wrong with the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the incorrect implementation is `call freeList`. But when the (recursive) call completes, it will try to return to the non-existent code after that line. Appending a `ret` instruction would make the code work, but normally you try to avoid that except when debugging code in which case it sometimes helps to be able to see all the intermediate calls. Instead you can simplify the `call freeList; ret` to a simple `jmp freeList`.

Example of debugging high-level code:

```
function freeList(list) {
    if (list) {
        var next = list->next;
        free(list);
        freeList(next);
    }
}
```

If you compile with optimisations, the compiler may want to write the recursive call to `freeList(next)` by coping `next` to `list` and performing a `jmp`, however this would destroy the value of `list`. This means that when you try to debug the function you can't tell what elements of the list have already been freed. So you would want to disable this optimisation when you are trying to debug a problem in the function.

Comment: So is it correct to say that alwayes after each `call X`, I need to write a `ret`?

Comment: You need to write something, because the call (unless you're calling abort or exit or something else similarly fatal) will at some point return back to the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a function, it is impossible to call it directly, as you would need to setup the stack frame before calling it, then unwind the frame after calling it. It also doesn't preserve EBX, which goes against most system ABI's (where only EAX, ECX and EDX are scratch registers)

if this is inlined code, then the the current frame would need to be unwound (which it is not).